# In Phaser3 ui objects are out of the scene because of the camera

Tags: javascript, user-interface, phaser-framework

I am making a platform game and my camera follows the player, the buttons or ui objects I put on the stage come out of the angle of the camera because the camera follows the player, for example, when the player comes down the platform, my button stays above.

I tried setScroll but it didn't work.

And also while the camera is following the player, everywhere outside of my tiledmap on your field is black empty and how do I prevent this, should I make my map bigger or is there another solution, for example I wanted to try setBounds but I was not successful because I cannot add setBounds when my camera is following the player.

```
export default class Level1Scene extends Scene {

 constructor() {
    super({
      key: Scenes.Level1Scene.key,
    });
    this.hitEnemy = this.hitEnemy.bind(this);
    this.uiManager = new UIManager();
  }

  init(props: any) {
    const { levelLoaded } = props;
    levelLoaded();
    console.log(LevelManager.instance.currentLevel + "11111111111111111");
    this.cursors = this.input.keyboard?.createCursorKeys();
    GameManager.instance.setScene(this);
  }

  create() {
    this.createPlayer();
    this.cameras.main.startFollow(this.player);
    this.cameras.main.setZoom(1.5);
    this.createTiles();
    this.createLayers();
    this.createBananas();
    this.createEnemies();
    this.createOverlaps();
    this.createUI();
    GameManager.instance.setScore(10);
  }

  update(time: number, delta: number): void {
    this.player.update();
    this.physics.collide(this.player, this.groundLayer);
    this.physics.collide(this.player, this.propsLayer);
    this.physics.collide(this.enemiesA, this.groundLayer);
    if (!LevelManager.instance.levelLoading) {
      if (this.cursors?.right.isDown) {
        LevelManager.instance.advanceLevel(Scenes.Level2Scene.key);
      }
    }
    this.bananas.getChildren().forEach((b) => b.update);
  }

  private createTiles(): void {
    this.map = this.make.tilemap({
      key: "level2",
    });

    this.map.setCollision([2]);
    this.propsTileset = this.map.addTilesetImage("props")!;
    this.groundTileset = this.map.addTilesetImage("ground")!;
  }

  private createLayers() {
    this.propsLayer = this.map.createLayer("props", this.propsTileset, 0, 0)!;
    this.groundLayer = this.map.createLayer(
      "ground",
      this.groundTileset,
      0,
      0
    )!;
    this.propsLayer.setCollisionBetween(293, 295);
  }

  private createPlayer() {
    this.player = Player.create(this);
  }

  private hitBanana(b: any, c: any) {
    (c as Banana).collect();
  }

  private hitEnemy(b: any, a: any) {}

  private createBananas() {
    this.bananas = this.physics.add.group({
      immovable: true,
      allowGravity: false,
    });
    const bananas = getObjectsByType("banana", this.map, "objects");
    bananas.forEach((b) => {
      this.bananas.add(
        new Banana({
          key: "banana",
          scene: this,
          texture: "banana32",
          x: b.x,
          y: b.y,
        })
      );
    });
  }

  private createEnemies() {
    //Create enemiesA
    this.enemiesA = this.physics.add.group({
      immovable: true,
      allowGravity: false,
    });
    const enemiesA = getObjectsByType("enemyA", this.map, "enemiesA");

    enemiesA.forEach((a) => {
      this.enemiesA.add(
        new EnemyA({
          key: "enemy",
          scene: this,
          texture: "enemyA",
          x: a.x,
          y: a.y - 16,
        })
      );
    });

    //Create enemiesB
    this.enemiesB = this.physics.add.group({
      immovable: true,
      allowGravity: false,
    });
    const enemiesB = getObjectsByType("enemiesB", this.map, "enemiesB");

    enemiesB.forEach((a) => {
      this.enemiesB.add(
        new EnemyB({
          key: "enemy",
          scene: this,
          texture: "enemyB",
          x: a.x,
          y: a.y - 16,
        })
      );
      ("");
    });
  }

  private createOverlaps() {
    this.enemiesA.getChildren().forEach((a) => {
      this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.enemiesA, this.hitEnemy);
    });

    this.enemiesB.getChildren().forEach((a) => {
      this.physics.add.collider(this.player, this.enemiesB, this.hitEnemy);
    });

    this.bananas.getChildren().forEach((b) => {
      this.physics.add.overlap(this.player, b, this.hitBanana, undefined, this);
    });
  }

  private createUI(): void {
    this.uiManager.add(
      "pauseBtn",
      () =>
        new IconBtn(this, 16, 16, "pauseBtn", () => {
          GameManager.instance.onPauseGame();
        })
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know, what `UIManager` is, that said for a UI, the best options is to all UI elements on its own `scene`. Check out [this official example](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/scenes/ui-scene-es6).

Basically you create a second Scene and like this the camera movement of the Game scene will not affect the UI scene.

**Here a short demo:**
*You can use the Left and Right Arrows to move the player (the white square)*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

class Game extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor () {
        super();
        this.moveCam = false;
    }

    create () {
        let gameWidth = config.width * 2;
        this.cameras.main.setBounds(0, 0, gameWidth, config.height);
        this.physics.world.setBounds(0, 0, gameWidth, config.height);
        this.scene.launch('UIScene');
        
        this.add.line(0, 0, 0, 0, gameWidth, config.height, 0xff0000).
          setOrigin(0);

        this.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

        let block = this.add.rectangle( 50, 50, 10, 10, 0xffffff);
        
        this.player = this.physics.add.existing(block);
        this.player.body.setCollideWorldBounds();
        this.cameras.main.startFollow(this.player, true);
    }

    update () {
        let speed = 100;

        this.player.body.setVelocity(0);

        if (this.cursors.left.isDown){
            this.player.body.setVelocityX(-speed);
        }
        else if (this.cursors.right.isDown){
            this.player.body.setVelocityX(speed);
        }
    }
}

class UI extends Phaser.Scene   {
    constructor() {
        super({ key: 'UIScene' });
    }

    create() {
        this.add.text(10,10, 'UI Stuff ....')
            .setOrigin(0);
    }
}

var config = {
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics: {  default: 'arcade' },
    scene: [Game, UI]
}; 

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

> **Extra Info:** *This official example also covers communication from one scene to the other. An alternative type of communication between scenes can be see in [this example](https://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src%5Cscenes%5Ccall%20function%20in%20another%20scene.js)*